# How can I extract all satellite adjectives from WordNet NLTK and save them to a text file?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to extract all satellite adjective synsets from WordNet and save them to a text file. Note that satellite adjectives are denoted as 's' in the synset name, e.g., "(fantastic.s.02)". The following is my code:

```
def extract_sat_adjectives():
    sat_adj_counter = 0
    sat_adjectives = []
    for i in wn.all_synsets():
        if i.pos() in ['s']:
            sat_adj_counter +=1
            sat_adjectives = sat_adjectives + [i.name()]
    fo = open("C:\\Users\\Nora\\Desktop\\satellite_adjectives.txt", "wb")
    for x in sat_adjectives:
        fo.write("%s\n" % x)
    fo.close()


extract_sat_adjectives()
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

How can I save the adjectives to the text file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the whole Traceback? Which line causes the TypeError?

Comment: I most certainly can: Message File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> C:\Users\Nora\Documents\module1.py 37  
    extract_sat_adjectives C:\Users\Nora\Documents\module1.py 32  
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Do you know which line is triggering the exception?

Comment: There is no line specified. I think it is because the items in the list are not strings, and thus can not be written to the text file.. But I am not sure..

Comment: We're asking about the line in the source code. Which line is line 32?

Comment: Line 32 is the function call extract_sat_adjectives()

Comment: Then you should include what is on line 37 (which is apparently below your pasted code snippet, since the function call is the last line provided).

Comment: There is nothing on 37. That is the last line, which is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to the combination of encoding errors and `str()`

```
for x in sat_adjectives:
    fo.write("%s\n" % x)
```

Change to:

```
for x in sat_adjectives:
    fo.write(bytes("%s\n" % x, 'UTF-8'))
```